# Multiple plots on common x axis in Matplotlib with common y-axis labeling

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have written the following minimal Python code in order to plot various functions of `x` on the same X-axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

xlabel='$X$'; ylabel='$Y$'

### Set tick features 
plt.tick_params(axis='both',which='major',width=2,length=10,labelsize=18)
plt.tick_params(axis='both',which='minor',width=2,length=5)
#plt.set_axis_bgcolor('grey') # Doesn't work if I uncomment!



lines = ["-","--","-.",":"]

Nlayer=4
f, axarr = plt.subplots(Nlayer, sharex=True)

for a in range(1,Nlayer+1):

     X = np.linspace(0,10,100)
     Y = X**a
     index = a-1 + np.int((a-1)/Nlayer)
     axarr[a-1].plot(X, Y, linewidth=2.0+index, color=cycle[a], linestyle = lines[index], label='Layer = {}'.format(a)) 
     axarr[a-1].legend(loc='upper right', prop={'size':6})


#plt.legend()


# Axes labels
plt.xlabel(xlabel, fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel(ylabel, fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```

However, the plots don't join together on the X-axis and I failed to get a common Y-axis label. It actually labels for the last plot (see attached figure). I also get a blank plot additionally which I couldn't get rid of.

I am using Python3.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The following code will produce the expected output :

- without blank plot which was created because of the two `plt.tick_params` calls before creating the actual `fig`
- with the `gridspec_kw` argument of `subplots` that allows you to control the space between `rows` and `cols` of `subplots` environment in order to join the different layer plots
- with unique and centered common `ylabel` using `fig.text` with relative positioning and `rotation` argument (same thing is done to `xlabel` to get an homogeneous final result). One may note that, it can also be done by repositioning the `ylabel` with `ax.yaxis.set_label_coords()` after an usual call like `ax.set_ylabel()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
xlabel='$X$'; ylabel='$Y$'
lines = ["-","--","-.",":"]

Nlayer = 4

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(Nlayer, sharex='col',gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0, 'wspace': 0})

X = np.linspace(0,10,100)
for i,ax in enumerate(axarr):
    Y = X**(i+1)
    ax.plot(X, Y, linewidth=2.0+i, color=cycle[i], linestyle = lines[i], label='Layer = {}'.format(i+1))
    ax.legend(loc='upper right', prop={'size':6})
```

with axes `labels`, first option :

```
fig.text(0.5, 0.01, xlabel, va='center')
fig.text(0.01, 0.5, ylabel, va='center', rotation='vertical')
```

or alternatively :

```
# ax is here, the one of the last Nlayer plotted, i.e. Nlayer=4
ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
ax.set_ylabel(ylabel) 
# change y positioning to be in the horizontal center of all Nlayer, i.e. dynamically Nlayer/2
ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.1,Nlayer/2)
```

which gives :

[image: output_figure]

I also simplified your `for` loop by using `enumerate` to have an automatic counter `i` when looping over `axarr`.

Comment: Thanks, but your plots do not join the panels at all. Also, `sharey` option spoils the Y-scale (all the curves look flat on the top three panels in your example) which I didn't want. I want the panels to be joined and put single Y-label on the left.

Comment: Regarding your comment, does my edited answer works for you now? Y-scale not spoiled anymore for the top three panels, and all of the panels are now "joined".