# Python Matplotlib lineplot with multiple x-axis data causing common y-axis issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, line-plot

New to Python and this is my first work with Matplotlib. I'm trying to plot multiple data sets on to a single lineplot but I'm having issues with getting the y-axis to display properly.

The x-axis is time in seconds. The y-axis are numerical values. All the data sets are brought in as a dictionary key:value pair where the value is a list.

Displaying one plot seems to work OK (Plot 1) but any time I add more than one data set - it looks like the y-axis is displaying a separate range for each of the plots (Plot 2)?

I have noticed that people seem to use numpy arrays rather than lists but I'm working with the format the data is in currently.

There was a similar question asked here [Multiple plots on common x axis in Matplotlib with common y-axis labeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546492/multiple-plots-on-common-x-axis-in-matplotlib-with-common-y-axis-labeling) but that person was seeing different issues to me.

```
kline_data_dict = {'time': ['14:27:00', '14:27:00', '14:27:00', '14:27:00', '14:27:02', '14:27:02', '14:27:02', '14:27:02', '14:27:04', '14:27:04'], 'open': ['20854.76000000', '20854.76000000', '20854.76000000', '20854.76000000', '20861.38000000', '20861.38000000', '20861.38000000', '20861.38000000', '20861.38000000', '20861.38000000'], 'close': ['20862.47000000', '20862.47000000', '20862.47000000', '20862.47000000', '20861.80000000', '20861.80000000', '20861.80000000', '20861.80000000', '20864.65000000', '20864.65000000'], 'high': ['20879.99000000', '20879.99000000', '20879.99000000', '20879.99000000', '20864.16000000', '20864.16000000', '20864.16000000', '20864.16000000', '20869.73000000', '20869.73000000'], 'low': ['20846.30000000', '20846.30000000', '20846.30000000', '20846.30000000', '20860.27000000', '20860.27000000', '20860.27000000', '20860.27000000', '20860.27000000', '20860.27000000']}

plt.plot(kline_data_dict['time'], kline_data_dict['low'])
plt.plot(kline_data_dict['time'], kline_data_dict['high'])
plt.show()
```

[Plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osli9.png)
[Plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhMhE.png)

Comment: Please clarify "the y-axis is displaying a separate range for each of the plots". Your data series have no overlap, so why would they not be separate in the plot?

Comment: @mcsoini I think I've found the issue causing this but there is overlap. In 'Plot 2' the bottom of the y-axis starts at 20846 and ends at 20869 but in the middle it is 20879 - so it's not in ascending order and both of the plots include common data point values. I'll update this post with what I think the problem is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer from this post:
[Matplotlib y axis values are not ordered [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062499/matplotlib-y-axis-values-are-not-ordered)

The list elements for the y-axis elements were input as strings. Converting them to float() seems to have solved this.

[Plot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNBGt.png)